# How add remind before END date of appointment?

Tags: outlook, uwp, windows-10-universal, appointment

I need add remind about appointment before end date, not start date.

This appointment's creation

```
private async void AddFavoriteTenderEndDateToCalendar(MyEvent event)
    {
            var appointment = new Appointment();

            appointment.StartTime = new DateTimeOffset(event.StartDate);

            appointment.Duration = event.EndDate - event.StartDate;

            appointment.Subject = "blahblah";

            appointment.Reminder = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

            var appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowEditNewAppointmentAsync(appointment);           
    }
```

Appointment have not property EndTime and instead I calc duration `appointment.Duration = event.EndDate - event.StartDate;`

How can I add reminder before `event.EndDate`?

Comment: Schedule a zero-duration appointment right after the end of the original appointment.

Comment: User will not confirm two events together every time.

Comment: It seems like no API can do this. And can you find the calendar do this?  If cannot, even the calendar cannot do this itself, how code do it? Change your design it the better way. Maybe @AxelKemper already provided you a good approach.